# Random World Generator

Tags: game-design

I'm a new game developer. I am working on my first game at the moment. It's sort of a Risk like game, but I have added my own elements. Also sort of Starcraft inspired. I want a random world generator for maps, but I'm having a little trouble making a generator. Tips?

Comment: http://pcg.wikidot.com/pcg-algorithm:map-generation

Comment: -1 for being so broad and showing complete lack of research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you will want some sort of random that you can use to generate your world. In the realm of games [Perlin Noise](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/noise/) is fairly common as a starting point for such a thing. Minecraft is a pretty well known game that [use/used this kind of technique](http://accidentalnoise.sourceforge.net/minecraftworlds.html) as well.

I am not sure if you are doing 2D or 3D but the algorithm follows in suit. There is an [article about the world generation](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/) for the game Realm of the Mad God that is also very useful to gather information on random world generation.

Another noise algorithm you may come across is [Simplex Noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_noise). [Here is an article on it in C++/Python](http://www.6by9.net/b/2012/02/03/simplex-noise-for-c-and-python) (since I am not sure which language you are interested in).

There is actually quite a bit of information out there. I find all this stuff fascinating and so have collected a good amount of URLs on the topics around it. I hope some of these will help you out.. The article on the Realm of the Mad God generation is fairly interesting in a thought provoking way as well (ie, what can I do with this set of algorithms).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Definitely check out Amit Patel’s posts on this topic (http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/)

Wonderful reading/resource.

Comment: @TimHolt Same article is linked in the answer :) But it is probably good enough to mention twice.

Comment: @James I think you forgot to link to the C++/Python article.

Comment: @Byte56 That I did, article has been linked into the answer.